# Why is my View utf8 and how can I change it to latin1

Tags: mysql, view, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I'm having an issue where a client program needs to use a View, but it needs the results as latin1.
Here's what I've got:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

mysql> Select CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, COLLATION_CONNECTION FROM information_schema.VIEWS v;
+----------------------+----------------------+
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | COLLATION_CONNECTION |
+----------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please show you database, table and view creation scripts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running the following commands:

```
SET character_set_client = latin1;
SET character_set_results = latin1;
SET character_set_connection = latin1;
DROP VIEW your_view;
CREATE VIEW your_view as (
    here_goes_your_view_query);
```

Basically we're recreating the view. I've tested it locally and it worked, even after setting the DB, the table and the column to default to utf8

Answer (score 0):

You need yo change your connection settings with the following commands:

```
    SET character_set_client=latin1
    SET character_set_connection=latin1
    SET character_set_results=latin1
```

Comment: They are all already set to latin1 as you can see from my query of global variables.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I read too fast. What kind of issue are you having? Do you have wrong encoded characters in your output?

Comment: Yes. They are coming out of the View as utf-8 and I have to (for business requirements) have them come out as latin1.